# How do I add strings together

Tags: ruby

The code below outputs 333 instead of 9.

How can I change it to print the sum calculation instead of the character concatenation?

```
puts 'What is your first name?'
first = gets.chomp
puts 'What is your middle name?'
middle = gets.chomp
puts 'What is your last name?'
last = gets.chomp
var1 = first.length.to_s
var2 = middle.length.to_s
var3 = last.length.to_s
puts 'Did you know there are '  + var1 + var2 + var3 + ' characters in your name, ' + first + ' ' +  middle + ' ' + last
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We don't care about your experience level, only that you try, show what you tried, and that you asked a well thought-out and clear question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Ruby understands the difference between a string and an integer/number:

```
'c'.class  # => String
1.class # => Fixnum
```

You have to tell Ruby to convert from the one to the other if you want to add numbers:

```
'1' + '2' # => "12"
1 + 2  # => 3
```

To convert a String value to a number we use `to_i`:

```
'1'.to_i + '2'.to_i # => 3
```

You already know that `chomp` is useful to remove trailing new-lines:

```
"a\n" # => "a\n"
"a\n".chomp # => "a"
```

but when converting to a number it's not necessary. `to_i` will convert the leading digits into a number and stop at the first non-digit:

```
"1\n".chomp.to_i # => 1
"1\n".to_i # => 1
```

and:

```
"12".to_i # => 12
"1 2".to_i # => 1
```

so use the easier:

```
"1\n".to_i # => 1
```

Note: `to_i` can do more than just convert from decimal (base 10) representation of numbers, it can do other bases:

```
"10000".to_i(2) # => 16
"20".to_i(8) # => 16
"10".to_i(16) # => 16
```

but that's something to grow into.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
puts 'What is your first name?'
first = gets.chomp

puts 'What is your middle name?'
middle = gets.chomp

puts 'What is your last name?'
last = gets.chomp

var1 = first.length
var2 = middle.length
var3 = last.length

puts "Did you know there are #{var1 + var2 + var3} characters in your name"
```

Notes: To add together the `var`s you shouldn't convert to strings. String-interpolation requires double-quotes. Good spacing helps readability big time.

Example:

```
$ What is your first name?
#James
$ What is your middle name?
#Tiberius
$ What is your last name?
#Kirk 
#Did you know there are 17 characters in your name
```

Comment: Strangely the only person to point out that *interpolation* can do this, no need for all that `+ ... .to_s ... +` cruft.

Answer (score 0):

You are first converting the length of names (integer) into strings and then trying to add them to another string. That's why the length shows up as 333. Instead of converting the length into strings, leave them as is (remove .to_s). And then perform an add for the numbers and finally convert to string.

```
var1 = first.length
var2 = middle.length
var3 = last.length

puts 'Did you know there are '  + (var1 + var2 + var3).to_s + ' characters in your name, ' + first + ' ' +  middle + ' ' + last
```